# chapter template

Tags: chapters

I need a template of chapter like the picture bellow:[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's easy with `titlesec`.  Here is an example. I used the `fourier` package to show what you can get without the default font.  The `clearempty` of `titlesec` suppreses page numbers and headers on empty pages, and `pagestyles` (not used here) allows you to define and apply new page styles, without `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, french]{book}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\filcenter}{\titlerule[0.6ex]\vspace{0.6ex}\titlerule[0.6pt]\vspace{2.5ex\bfseries}%
\chaptername~\thechapter\vspace{2.5ex}\\\titlerule[0.6pt]}{2.5ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{48pt}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{État de l’art}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `fourier` and `geometry` are not at all necessary for the example, nor are the `pagestyles` and `clearempty` options. (And `1pt` is clearly a typo.)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing the typo. I added some explanations about fourier and the  titlesec options loaded here.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Conny style from the [fncychap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap?lang=en) package; see Section 3.4 (page 7) of the documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % to have chapitre instead of chapter
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\ChNameAsIs % this changes the default CHAPITRE to Chapitre
\ChTitleAsIs % this does the same with the title

\begin{document}

\chapter{Etat de l'art}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```